# 2D image to 3D world coordinate in perspective view

Tags: object-detection, projection, camera-calibration, perspective

I have been trying to locate detected objects from 2D image in the 3D space for a single fixed camera installed at the height.
I went trough the similar questions, but the perspective view is not mentioned.
What I have:

- The height of the camera
- Calibration parameters
- The exact location of one fixed object in view

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a set of solutions to this kind of problem. 3d points reconstruction from 2d coordinates (yes, "in perspective"), are obtained by means of the extrinsics matrix. See https://github.com/rodolfoap/screen2world-k. Other methods are linked from there.